# Dynamically load picture with glide into ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-glide

I would like to load Image with `Glide` into my `ImageView` that is `ActionLayout`

This is my menu item

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:title="Menu"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_action_layout"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

This is my action layout

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is how I load it

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)

    val menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu)
    val rootView = menuItem.actionView
    val profileImageView = rootView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.profileImageView)
    val url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vauhd1q4nhoz7pn/ronaldo_profile.jpg?dl=1"
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .into(profileImageView)
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't load the image. I've tried with normal drawable and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load image from Dropbox like that you need to change the "https://www.dropbox.com" with "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com" so your url will looks like : "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vauhd1q4nhoz7pn/ronaldo_profile.jpg"

Comment: It works in normal `ImageView`, outside `ActionBar`. I set `dl=1` to have a hotlink from `Dropbox`